# Не выводится текст из spring bean

Tags: java, spring

Пытаюсь освоить Spring. Делаю все по видео [Spring Потрошитель](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmBr5diz8WA&list=PLrSBxgb4d8dHj6f8zinGVbjwJ3kp_PtqD), но на экран ничего не выходит. Вроде бин класса `InjectRandomIntAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` просто игнорируется.

Просьба подсказать в чем проблема?

Сам бин:

```
public class TerminatorQuoter implements Quoter {
private String message;

@InjectRandomInt(min = 2, max = 7)
private int repeat;

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public void sayQuote() {
    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
        System.out.println("message = s" + message);
    }
}
```

Аннотация:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InjectRandomInt {
int min();
int max();
}
```

BeanPostProcessor:

```
public class InjectRandomIntAnnotationBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    Field[] fields = bean.getClass().getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        InjectRandomInt injectRandomInt = field.getAnnotation(InjectRandomInt.class);
        if (injectRandomInt != null){
            int min = injectRandomInt.min();
            int max = injectRandomInt.max();
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomInt = min + random.nextInt(max - min);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            ReflectionUtils.setField(field, bean, randomInt);
        }
    }
    return bean;
}

public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
}
```

XML:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean class="quoters.InjectRandomIntAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="quoters.TerminatorQuoter" id="terminatorQuoter">
    <property name="message" value="I'll be back!!!"/>
</bean>
```

Main.java (собственно откуда текст и не выходит):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
    context.getBean(TerminatorQuoter.class).sayQuote();
}
```

Comment: ошибки есть хоть какие?

Comment: Нет, просто пустой экран (Process finished with exit code 0). IDE  intellij idea может там куда посмотреть?

Comment: IDE intellij idea - самый продвинутый, ошибка явно в коде

Comment: попробуйте добавить getter & setter

Comment: а код откуда брали? или сами?

Comment: Код с видео Евгения Борисова Spring потрошитель.

Comment: А зачем Get и Set, если все должно идти через аннотацию, я же в XML проперти не указываю?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вызов `bean.getClass().getFields();` возвращает лишь `public` поля. Замените этот вызов на `bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields();`.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо! Еще вопрос, а можно ли обойтись без " ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        context.getBean(TerminatorQuoter.class).sayQuote(); "? Например в Servletах, как указать что используется context.xml?

Comment: @Vadim если ответ решил вашу проблему, то вам стоит принять его, нажав галочку рядом с ним.

Comment: ОК, сделал, спасибо за комментарии.

Comment: @Vadim Можно: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-web-contexts